# Making a service port externally visible

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to deploy a simple containerized app on GCE. I've created a deployment file and a service file.  The latter includes `type: NodePort` and `"ports": [{"port": 443, "targetPort": "myapp-port", "protocol": "TCP"}]` declarations.

After running `kubectl create -f deployment.json` and `kubectl create -f service.json`, the deployment (including pods and replica sets) and service are created.  However, the service is not visibly externally.  How do I make it so?  Preferably I would want to make this change in the `service.json` file, so it's under revision control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because you missed

```
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
```

http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/load-balancer/